# Malloc to allocate the exact size of a string

Tags: c, malloc

How is the best way to allocate the exact size of a string using `malloc`?

I tested

```
malloc((strlen(str) * sizeof(char));
```

And it didn't work when i tried to copy the same string into the allocated region, but the following worked:

```
malloc((strlen(str) + 10) * sizeof(char));
```

If I try using +1 insted of +10, would it also work properly? Why can't it be just the string length?

Also:

```
char str[100] = "string!";
malloc(sizeof(str));
```

How much memory does this allocate? Would it allocate based on the size of the string array (100) or its length (7)?

Comment: look up "null terminator

Comment: `strlen()` returns a length in bytes, there's no need to compute `sizeof(char)`. For more exotic "string" types where bytes and characters differ, other functions are involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in C need to be NUL-terminated, that is, there is always a `\0` character after the last character of the string. So something like `"apple"` has a length of 5, but contains **6** characters total, including the terminator. The `strlen()` function returns the length of a string, which is the number of characters preceding the terminator, therefore if you want to calculate the actual minimum size needed to store a string in memory you will need to add 1 to the value returned by `strlen()`.

The correct way to allocate space for a string is:

```c
malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

By the way, if you want to simply copy a string, the `strdup()` function does exactly this for you, and it's simpler to use than a manual `malloc` + `memcpy`/`strcpy`.

---

In the case of `char str[100] = "string!";` the size of the array you define is `100`. The first 7+1 characters are initialized with the content of the string literal (7 characters plus the terminator), but the array is still a 100-element array. So `sizeof(str)` here returns `100`, and the `malloc()` call allocates `100` bytes.

Comment: Just for curiosity, when i'm using an array such as A[6] = "string" it would alloc 7 bytes of memory since there will be 6 bytes for the characters and + 1 for the \0?

Comment: @FelipeWatanabe doing `char A[6] = "string";` would create an invalid string, as there is not enough space in `A` to hold 6+1 characters, thus you would end up with a 6 character array without a terminator. If you explicitly specify the size, that's what you'll get, whether it's more or less than the literal you are using to initialize the array.

Comment: Welcome to the world of off-by-one errors, one of the most subtle, yet persistent types of bugs.

Comment: @FelipeWatanabe you can declare just `char a[] = "string";` and the compiler will know what to do. And if you print `sizeof(a)` you will get 7, as expected

Answer (score 2):

For knowing the end of a string, there must be an endmark. That is `'\0'`. So when you are writing -

```
char str[100] = "string!";
```

it is saved like this - [image]

So you need 1 more character than the `strlen(str)` gives you. `sizeof(str)` is working because it is giving the size of 100 size character array you have declared.

Comment: Note that the remaining bytes of `str` are initialized to `'\0'` as well, including if the definition appears in a local scope.